# DataForm IsItemChanged does not reset after SubmitChanges on datasource

Tags: silverlight, dataform

I am creating a silverlight app using the RIA services and the dataform. Everything works ok except that the dirty flag in the header of the dataform remains visible after I submit changes on my 'DomainDataSource'. The changes do get commited to the database but the dataform does not notice this and keeps the dirty flag. Is there a way to reset the dataform programmaticaly or to never show the asteriks?

Looking in the debugger is see that the Dataform.IsItemChanged property remains true after submitting changes back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because EndEdit was not called on the entity, entity implements IEditableObject. You are probably doing BeginEdit but you are not calling EndEdit and you are submitting your changes before EndEdit was called by data form.

Comment: I am not doing any explicit beginedit. It might be done bij the dataform but that should call EndEdit as well.